# Calculating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{(1+t^2)^3}\text{d}t$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I am very new to the Residuetheorem and now I am asked to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{(1+t^2)^3}\text{d}t$$

I know it has poles of order $3$ at $x=\pm i$ and that I have to find a closed curve in order to calculate it.

But as I said, I am very new to this and (to be hounest) a little lost at the moment. Therefore any hint or help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Because the integrand is even, the integral is half of that evaluated along the entire real axis. Furthermore, we can say $\cos t = \mathrm{Re}[e^{it}]$ and apply [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).

Comment: Not residue based, but I posted a more generalised form (seeking Real Methods) yesterday and was fortunate to have a solution that was simple and elegant. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284703/i-nt-a-int-0-infty-frac-cosxt-leftx2-a2-rightn-dx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on what I put as my comment, the standard approach to this integral would be to realize that
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos t}{(1+t^2)^3}\, dt = \frac{1}{2}\textrm{Re}\left[\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma(R)}\frac{e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^3}\, dz\right]$$ where $\gamma(R)$ is the contour that goes from $-R$ to $R$ along the real axis and travels along a semicircle in the upper half-plane to complete the loop. Using [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma), we can see that the upper semicircle's contribution to the integral vanishes in the limit. Our only residue in this contour is the one at $i$, which may be easily calculated to be
$$\textrm{Res}\left[\frac{e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^3}, i\right] = \frac{1}{2!}\lim_{z\to i}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z + i)^3} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to i}\left(\frac{-e^{iz}}{(z+i)^3} - \frac{6ie^{iz}}{(z+i)^4} + \frac{12e^{iz}}{(z+i)^5}\right) = \frac{7}{16ie}$$
Thus, our loop integral evaluates to $2\pi i\textrm{Res}(i) = \frac{7\pi}{8e}$, meaning our original integral is merely $\boxed{\frac{7\pi}{16e}}$

Answer (score 3):

Note that your integral is equal to$$\frac12\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{it}}{(1+t^2)^3}\,\mathrm dt\right).$$And$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{it}}{(1+t^2)^3}\,\mathrm dt=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=i}\frac{e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^3}.$$Finally, this last residue is equal to $-\frac{7i}{16e}$. Therefore, your integral is equal to $\frac{7\pi}{16e}$.